# Is it possible to start (and stop) a thread inside a DLL?

Tags: delphi, dll, delphi-7

I'm pondering some ideas for building a DLL for some common stuff I do. One thing I'd like to check if it's possible is running a thread inside of a DLL. I'm sure I would be able to at least start it, and have it automatically free on terminate (and make it forcefully terminate its self) - that I can see wouldn't be much of a problem. But once I start it, I don't see how I can continue communicating with it (especially to stop it) mainly because each call to the DLL is unique (as far as my knowledge tells me) but I also know very little of the subject.

I've seen how in some occasions, a DLL can be loaded at the beginning and released at the end when it's not needed anymore. I have 0 knowledge or experience with this method, other than just seeing something related to it, couldn't even tell you what or how, I don't remember. But is this even possible?

I know about ActiveX/COM but that is not what I want - I'd like just a basic DLL that can be used across languages (specifically C#).

Also, if it is possible, then how would I go about doing callbacks from the DLL to the app? For example, when I start the thread, I most probably will assign a function (which is inside the EXE) to be the handler for the events (which are triggered from the DLL).

So I guess what I'm asking is - how to load a DLL for continuous work and release it when I'm done - as opposed to the simple method of calling individual functions in the DLL as needed. In the same case - I might assign variables or create objects inside the DLL. How can I assure that once I assign that variable (or create the object), how can I make sure that variable or object will still be available the next time I call the DLL? Obviously it would require a mechanism to Initialize/Finalize the DLL (I.E. create the objects inside the DLL when the DLL is loaded, and free the objects when the DLL is unloaded).

**EDIT:** In the end, I will wrap the DLL inside of a component, so when an instance of the component is created, DLL will be loaded and a corresponding thread will be created inside the DLL, then when the component is free'd, the DLL is unloaded. Also need to make sure that if there are for example 2 of these components, that there will be 2 instances of the DLL loaded for each component.

Is this in any way related to the use of an IInterface? Because I also have 0 experience with this.

No need to answer it directly with sample source code - a link to a good tutorial would be great.

Comment: On the last note there, I mean I don't expect anyone to take the time and answer this in detail, I know it's a big subject, all I need is for someone to show me a tutorial to do this, without using ActiveX.

Comment: Starting threads that you cannot communicate with and control is a bad idea.

Comment: Indeed, 'tis why I'm trying to figure out how to communicate with them after they've started.

Comment: I found this webpage: http://www.delphi3000.com/articles/article_1366.asp?SK= which describes exactly what I was trying to find out (load/unload dll) - but is this thread safe?

Comment: Thread safe itself is meaningless without describing your threading model. One thread per instance? One global instance? Is your question really about  how to use LoadLibrary? If so don't rely on that article.

Comment: I will be using a TThread descendent (the one you mentioned isn't made for D7), one per instance.

Comment: The class which you ask about is not descended from TThread. Anyway, I believe you have D2010, why make life hard for yourself?

Comment: I'm not making life hard for myself - I'm making tasks challenging for myself. The more I do things like this, the better I learn for the future. If I'm always stuck taking the easy way out all the time, then how can I get to be such a genius as yourself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The basic pattern you are looking for goes like this:

1. EXE calls a function in DLL.
2. EXE passes parameters as necessary.
3. DLL performs work, starts thread, returns a handle. And by handle I mean in the loose sense of the work rather than meaning a Windows handle.
4. EXE can now communicate further with DLL by calling more functions, passing the handle.
5. DLL can communicate with EXE, e.g. by callbacks, so long as EXE has supplied callbacks.
6. When it is time to stop, the EXE calls a DLL function, passing the handle. At this point the DLL tidies up.

Behind the handle lies whatever state the DLL needs to keep track of between calls. From the point of view of the EXE this handle is opaque.

This sort of pattern can work just fine even with non-OOP languages like C. However, it's much easier to use OOP facilities. Since you are wishing to cross module boundaries you will be much safer using interfaces rather than Delphi objects. If you pass Delphi objects across module boundaries then you can only pass the data part of the object, but not the code part.

When using interfaces, the interface variable returned by the DLL functions as the handle in my numbered list above. It contains any instance data. Use of interfaces allows for ready extensibility.

As for the threading part, you would do well to use a higher level threading library rather than raw threads. The library I would recommend is Primož Gabrijelčič's [OmniThreadLibrary](http://otl.17slon.com/).

Regarding your edit:

> I will wrap the DLL inside of a component, so when an instance of the component is created, DLL will be loaded and a corresponding thread will be created inside the DLL, then when the component is free'd, the DLL is unloaded. Also need to make sure that if there are for example 2 of these components, that there will be 2 instances of the DLL loaded for each component.

When you load a DLL into a process there is only ever a single instance of it. In particular if you intend to use global variables, there will be just a single instance of each global variable, not matter how many times you call `LoadLibrary`.

Comment: So just to make sure I understand correctly: If I have a variable declared in the DLL, and I send a call to the DLL which sets that variable, then the next time I call another function in the DLL, that variable will still be assigned how it was the last call? I'm afraid to try without knowing for sure it's possible first.

Comment: If you use a global variable, sure. But you don't want to do that. Not least since you have threads. So store the state in the object behind the handle or interface.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to post this as a comment but ran out of characters: the short answer is yes, it should be possible. Designing the API so it is synchronized and works well is another story. I usually get onto the TCP/IP networking soap box for cross-platform/language communication, but especially in an environment where you're looking for asynchronous operations. It wouldn't be hard to design a service that has a "Start" "Stop" and "isReady" call.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.TThread

You're diving into territory that will allow race conditions and requires some smart checks to be effective. Just be aware of that and read up on the subject.

Here's the basics on creating a DLL:
http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/a/dll_basics.htm

And here's the basics on using one. I've been away from Delphi for a couple years otherwise I'd whip up a quick example, I have not had the urge to purchase a copy for myself, but the principles are the same across all languages. There's loads of Java/C# tutorials out there on threading and interface design.

Generally speaking a "Simple" Setup might be:

Class
  - Object WorkToBeDone
  - boolean isRunning
  - boolean isReady
  - procedure stop;
  - procedure start (work);
  - function isReady() : boolean;

Your thread would run in a while loop of the structure:

```
procedure start(work) //inside new thread
begin
  isRunning := true;
  isReady := false;

  while(isRunning)
    begin
      doIncrementalOperationOnWork();
      thread.yield;
    end;
  work := thread.getWork();
  isRunning := false;
  isReady := true;

end;
```

Its a crude sketch, but the idea is the outside caller can check to see if it is ready and return when it is. I'm not sure what you're doing but that's a "possible" solution. It is just a lot to manage and, as Delphi states: 16 threads per CPU is their "upper" limit. Just be aware of the constraints. Other people might have better suggestions, this is just an abstract pattern I use to offload work onto threads that seems to be simple and straight-forward.

Comment: Some good points, but not quite the answer I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, from the documentation in the link [above](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.TThread) : 'Keeping track of too many threads consumes CPU time; the recommended limit is 16 active threads per process on single processor systems.'

Comment: If your threads do work you want 1 per core. If your threads are waiting then more than 16 per core is fine, although rather pointless. Any limits are nothing to do with Delphi and in fact determinted by the underlying system. If you have too many in a single 32 bit process then the 1MB stack reserve per core can rapidly exhaust resources.

Comment: And here is a link to an article [Pushing the Limits of Windows: Processes and Threads](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2009/07/08/3261309.aspx) by Mark Russinovich, which in detail tests and explains limits on thread resources and other windows resources in a 32 and 64 bit windows system.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of questions and days of fun packed learning experiences.

Loading and unloadng dlls isn't hard, you add a function called dllMain. It's a special fellow that windows uses when being asked to load and unload dlls. More details here

[About Delphi](http://delphi.about.com/cs/adptips2003/a/bltip1003_2.htm)

Plenty of articles about delphi and threading, and how to use Interfaces in delphi.

When you get some more specific questions, I should be able to help. However as a Delphi and C# Programmer, I'd be writing this stuff in C#, wrapping it for Com and then calling it from Delphi. You'll get a lot more help, find more tutorials, and the language support particularly in complex scenarios is way better.

BackgroundWorker, and thread pooling, not to mention parallel extensions make threading in .net fun. In Delphi, it's just painful.

Comment: There are plentty of people of the do threading in Delphi. There are a number of good threading libraries writing in C# and using interop does not sound like a great idea to me.

Comment: Aye me too, but if I had the choice of threading in c# or Delphi, I know which one I'd be picking.

Comment: How acceptable COM, or even a service would be depends mainly on how much information has to be passed back and forth and what level of decoupling can be afforded. If its just DoTask and tell me when you've finished and the tasks are defined in the .net code...

Answer (score 0):

Threads exist inside of a PROCESS.

A process runs executable code: either code built in to the .exe, or code loaded from an external .dll.

A process can also run code "remotely" - code in a separate process, or even a separate machine - with technologies like DCOM (Microsoft COM/ActiveX), WCF (Microsoft .Net), RMI (Java) or CORBA/IIOP (among others).

Since you posted on a Delphi forum, your best bet might be to investigate Delphi Prism:

http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/41598

If you're stuck with an old version of Delphi 7, your best bet might be to just stick with raw sockets to communicate with remote PC's.

Comment: just to note since we're on top of each other: I don't think my example is a good design choice, it is a technical answer to the question.

Comment: Where did communicating with remote PC's come into the question? And I mentioned in two places I don't want to use ActiveX intentionally. And I also do not want to move away from Delphi7 - I've actually downgraded from Delphi 2010.

Comment: -1. This does nothing to answer the question asked, which did not mention anything about "communicating with remote PCs", wasn't asked in a Delphi forum (this is StackOverflow), and has nothing to do with using Prism instead of Delphi. The question is about threads in a Delphi DLL.

Comment: Really? A revenge downvote? On an old post that has 30 upvotes?

Comment: Don't feel bad, I had someone go through every single post of mine and downvote them last week for some stupid reason.